# S3 Security regarding Restrict S3 object access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use S3 to stock static files for my website. Since my website has a login password, I would like to limit access to the static files on S3.

I successfully set the access permission like below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://mywebsite.com/*",
                        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then, I tried to access the image directly by inputting the URL.  I got the result(please see the attached).

**My question:
Do you think it is safe to expose RequestID and HostID from a security perspective?**

[XML image. This is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYDhy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Request ID and Host ID are identifiers within Amazon S3 that can be used for debugging and support purposes. There is no harm in S3 exposing that information, and you cannot prevent that information from appearing.

Also, please note that using `aws:referer` is a rather **insecure method** of protecting your content, since it can be easily spoofed (faked) when making a request to S3.

If you wish to protect valuable/confidential information in Amazon S3, then you should:

- Keep all content in S3 as **private** (no bucket policy)
- Users authenticate to your **back-end app**
- When a user wants to access some private content from S3, your back-end app checks that they are **entitled to access the content**. If so, the back-end generates an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.
- This can be provided as a direct link, or included in an HTML page (eg `<img src="...">`)
- When S3 receives the pre-signed URL, it **verifies the signature and checks the expiry time**. If they are valid, it then returns the private object from the S3 bucket.

This way, you can use S3 to serve static content, but your application has full control over *who* is permitted to access the content. It cannot be faked like `referer` since each request is signed with a hash of the Secret Key.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you so much for sharing your expertise and now I understand how it works.  Also, the additional information is very helpful for me.  I am very pleased by your kindness.  Again, thank you so much!